# Count an observation based on condition of another variable

Tags: r, count, sum

I have dataset of regional patent. I want to count where how many Appln_id has more than one Person_id and how many Apply_id has only one Person_id.

```
Appln_id 3 3 3 10 10 10 10 2 4 4
Person_id 23 22 24 49 50 55 51 101 122 104
```

here Appln_id 3 has three different person_id (23,22,24) and Appln_id 2 has only one Person_id(101). So, I want to count them that how many of Appln_id has more than one Person_id and how many Apply_id has only one Person_id

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you tell me how to calculate the occurance rate, i mean the the percentage of occurance (of n). then I want to show them in a barplot

Answer (score 0):

Count number of unique person for each `Appln_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(Appln_id) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(Person_id))
result

#  Appln_id     n
#*    <int> <int>
#1        2     1
#2        3     3
#3        4     2
#4       10     4
```

Now you can count how many of them have only 1 `Person_id` and how many of them have more than that.

```
sum(result$n == 1)
#[1] 1

sum(result$n > 1)
#[1] 3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Appln_id = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 
4L, 4L), Person_id = c(23L, 22L, 24L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 51L, 101L, 
122L, 104L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(n = uniqueN(Person_id)), by = Appln_id]
```